# Paypal Buy Now Button

Tags: php, html, paypal

I am New to PHP and PayPal Buttons

**Note**: I am talking about mysql item

I am Trying to Make A Shop But When Using PayPal "Buy Now" Buttons but if a customer Buys The Product What Happens Next The Website Gets The money but nothing happen to The Custom Who Bought The Product Gets Nothing

You might say you can redirect them to a Page That Gives Them their product But You Can Easily Go To The Page that gives them their product with paying

What i want is to change a mysql value to 1 from 0 if a customer pays if not then the mysql value doesn't change

Thanks :D

Comment: You may want to review [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you should use either the [PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) system](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/), [PayPal Payment Data Transfer (PDT) system](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/), or perhaps a combination of both.

[This page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/) provides a good overview of both IPN and PDT; covering their uses, features, pros and cons. In general, PDT is preferable when a website needs **immediate** confirmation of that a specified user has submitted a payment. On the other hand, if you and your users do not mind waiting a few minutes (or quite possibly a few hours), then IPN is the way to go. I recommend visiting the pages linked above for further information.

As a personal recommendation, I use a combination of both PDT and IPN on my e-commerce websites. However, you need to be careful doing this so you do not accidently process payments twice. (Keep a database containing transaction IDs of all processed payments and reference this database before processing a "new" payment.)